Как в макросе Javascript вывести на печать таблицу
Есть таблица в Р7 офисе:
Требуется распечатать кол-во страниц, указанные в ячейке B2, с заменой номера заголовка в А1. В данном примере должно распечататься 8 страниц с номерами с 1 по 8.


(function() { 
    
 for (var index = 1; index <= Api.GetActiveSheet().GetRange("C2").GetValue(); index++)  { 
  Api.GetActiveSheet().GetRange("A1:A3").PrintOut; 
  Api.GetActiveSheet().GetRange("A1").SetValue("ВЕДОМОСТЬ ОТКЛОНЕНИЙ №" + index); 
 }  
})();



Вопрос в том, как отправлять на печать эту таблицу по нажатию на кнопку? Сейчас при выполнении макроса ничего не происходит, диалоговое окно печати не открывается. Информации в Интернете крайне мало, может быть это вообще невозможно?
